# How to specify from what stylesheet the class is being called

Tags: html, css

If I have two different stylesheets and a class name that is being shared on both of them, something like this:

**Home.css:**

```
.myClass{
color: red;
}
```

**Sales.css:**

```
.myClass{
color: blue;
}
```

And now I would like to be able to to something like this:

```
<div class = "Sales.css.myClass" >....</div>  <!--Here I am calling the blue color from Sales.css-->
```

Is there any way to specify from what stylesheet is the class I want to call?

Comment: I don't pretend to be a CSS expert but this looks like a very wrong way to do things.

Comment: No.  They are one class.

Comment: @apokryfos When you say the wrong way is it because I shouldn't have two different classes with the same name or there is something else wrong?

Comment: The one active will be the one from the stylesheet linked last.

Comment: Not posible the last added css file will override the previously defined class

Comment: Okay I guess I got the answer for this question. Thank you

Comment: @Mystia Yes using the same class name to specify two different concepts (in this case blue and red coloured text) is not a very good idea. Ideally you'd want to either use a different name, or be more specific on when you want each rule to be applied.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you, well explained!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS file priority depend on the sequence of files you have defined in the header, having the last one picked up, unless your rule has higher specificity.

However, what you are trying to do is a bad practice, leading to reduced readability and maybe conflicts.

Why don't you just put your rule to different rules in each file:

```
/*Home.css*/
.myHomeClass{
  color: red;
}

/*Sales.css*/
.mySalesClass{
  color: blue;
}
```

And then put the one you want to your element?

```
<div class = "mySalesClass" >....</div>
```

Comment: Sounds good to me, just wanted to know is it possible or not, and obviously it is not a good practice since 10 people said that already. Will mark your answer as the correct one in 6 minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Well, this is not a good way of doing this indeed.
You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Simple CSS rule: later rule extends previous rules for same class.

That is

```
.myClass {
   color: red;
   font-size: 14px;
}

.myClass {
   color: blue;
}
```

`.myClass` will be blue 14px font size.

Also you specify `.myClass` in CSS but your class in HTML `Sales.css.myClass` and that's different classes. Do you mean `Sales css myClass`?